# Using subquery in update statement

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have 2 tables A and B. I need to run an update on table A but getting one value from one field in table B to be assigned to one field in table A,

The code as the following:

```
Update [A]    
    set A.Code = 10,
        A.Name = 'Test',
        A.Link = (Select Link from [B] where [B].ID = 10)    
    from [A]
```

The problem, the value in A.Link is always empty!!!!

Any idea what's wrong

Thanks,

Comment: If you run the subquery what sort of result set gets returned?

Comment: I get the correct value when I run the subquery in separate query

Comment: I don't see a WHERE clause. Do you really intend to UPDATE *all* the rows in table A?

Comment: @Mark - I'm asking, if you run the subquery do you get a **single row** or a **set of rows**?

Comment: @Mark - I notice that the subquery is not correlated to anything in the [A] table. Is that correct? Presumably, you could query for the Link value in [B] where ID = 10 and just update [A].Link with that static value for all rows correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does A.Code = B.ID? If so ...

```
UPDATE A
  SET A.LINK = B.LINK
     ,A.NAME = 'TEST'
FROM
  TABLE_A A
  INNER JOIN TABLE_B B
    ON A.CODE = B.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

using joins can be more efficient,

```
Update [A]
set A.Code = 10,
    A.Name = 'Test',
    A.Link = B.Link    
from [A]
join [B] on [A].ID = [B].ID
where [B].ID=10;
```

Hope this works!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 Update [A]
 set A.Code = 10, 
     A.Name = 'Test', 
     A.Link = ISNULL((Select Link from [B] where [B].ID = 10),'it was null')
 from [A]

 SELECT * FROM [A] WHERE Name = 'Test'
```

Does is have the custom `it was null` message in the Link column?